# Why data.reponseText is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain

Why does `data.reponseText` in the following code not contain anything while it works in browser?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.xdomainajax.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
      $.get('http://www.vtb24.ru/_layouts/Vtb24.Pages/CurrencyRateAjax.aspx', function(data) {
        console.log(data.responseText);
      });
    };
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

You can find "jquery.xdomainajax.js" here -- https://github.com/padolsey/jquery.fn/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show us what data is? you can use console.log(data)

Comment: @Anoop Joshi It gives me "Object {responseText: ""}"

Comment: @FrozenHeart then it is correct. what is the issue?

Comment: @Jai The problem is that it should return valid HTML page like in the browser but it doesn't